# Java Linked list adding Tail

Tags: java

I am learning `Linked List` in Java and I am trying to add numbers to the tail, say a 10 Numbers. However, after insertion I am only able to retrieve the last two numbers, I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
    import java.util.*;
public class LinkTry
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sx = new Scanner(System.in);
        Node N = new Node();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            Node last = new Node();

            while(N.link!=null)
                N=N.link;

            last.data = sx.nextInt();
            N.link = last;

        }

        System.out.println("");


        for(Node x=N;x!=null;x=x.link)
            System.out.print("-->"+x.data);

    }

    public static class Node
    {
        int data;
        Node link;
    }
}
```

I am having a bit trouble how address is passed on here, an answer that explains the memory addressing in Linked list would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this line:

```
                N=N.link;
```

causes `N` to no longer point to the head of the list, whereas this line:

```
        for(Node x=N;x!=null;x=x.link)
```

assumes that `N` still points to the head of the list.

To fix this, you need to use separate variables — you need to keep separate references to the head of the list (for later reference) and the tail of the list (for appending elements there).

Comment: Alright, I was wondering how does these objects points to one another? Any good link that's worth a read for a beginner?

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LinkTry
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sx = new Scanner(System.in);
        Node first = null;
        Node last = null; 

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            Node current = new Node();
            current.data = sx.nextInt();

            if (first == null) {
                first = current;
                last = current;
            } else {
                last.link = current;
                last = current;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("");


        for(Node x=first;x!=null;x=x.link)
            System.out.print("-->"+x.data);

    }

    public static class Node
    {
        int data;
        Node link;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the for loop. As you are iterating through the loop you have lost reference to the head of the List you started with i.e., `Node N = new Node();`

Issue in the for loop, highlighted between ** ** below

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    Node last = new Node();

    while(N.link!=null)
        N=N.link;

    last.data = sx.nextInt();
    **N.link = last;**

}
```

At the end of 10 iterations, now 'N' is pointing to last but one Node. And so it is printing only last 2 items.